# Object.assign bombing on second loop through data

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

When I initially load the page (PHP), I populate the JSON object calHTML with 3 months of data for each of the 4 baseball fields (field management calendar tool for local youth sports org).

calHTML is this:

```
{
   "Field 1":{
      "Apr 2021":{
         "html":"some html"
      },
      "May 2021":{
         "html":"more html"
      },
      "Jun 2021":{
         "html":"even more html"
      }
   },
   "Field 2":{
      "Apr 2021":{
         "html":"some html"
      },
      "May 2021":{
         "html":"more html"
      },
      "Jun 2021":{
         "html":"even more html"
      }
   },
   "Field 3":{
      "Apr 2021":{
         "html":"some html"
      },
      "May 2021":{
         "html":"more html"
      },
      "Jun 2021":{
         "html":"even more html"
      }
   },
   "Field 4":{
      "Apr 2021":{
         "html":"some html"
      },
      "May 2021":{
         "html":"more html"
      },
      "Jun 2021":{
         "html":"even more html"
      }
   }
}
```

Then when the user moves to another month on the calendar, I fetch more data from the database.  It's getting the calendar HTML and I want to add it to the JSON object.

```
   $.ajax({
       type: "GET",
       url: ROOT_URL +"/getBookingMonth",
       data: "monthToGet="+mo,
       success: function(json){
        let data = JSON.parse(json);
        console.log(data);
        if(data){
                    $.each(data, function(k, v){
                        console.log('this record');
                        console.log(k);
                        console.log(v);
                        console.log('updating object');
                        let html = v[mo]['html'];
                        let propPath = `["${k}"].["${mo}"].html`;
                        console.log('propPath: ' + propPath);
                        let newCal = Object.assign(calHTML[k],v); <--- BOMBING HERE
                        calHTML = newCal;
                        console.log(calHTML);
                        //calHTML[k][mo]['html'] = v[mo]['html'];
                        return;
                    });
```

It's bombing on let newCal = Object.assign(calHTML[k],v); but ONLY ON THE SECOND iteration. Error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object

Why is this happening and how can I fix it???

Comment: Afaik, in jquery's each, `k` is the numerical index and `v` is the element. `calHTML` however is an object and doesn't have `calHTML[0]` or `calHTML[1]`, etc. What exactly is `data`? Is it an array? Or is it also an object?

Comment: @ChrisG I updated it with more of the code.  data is the returned, parsed JSON with the user-requested month's html.  it's in the EXACT same structure as included above. k is "Field 1" or 2, 3,4 (the key within the data structure). v is month (a deeper key) and html.

Comment: Ok, so what's the logging output? Do you see the Field keys and month data as expected? Can you create a [mre]?

Comment: @ChrisG Thanks for helping me out.  I just figured out the problem.  It's because in the process of assigning the new data to calHTML, when I assign newCal to calHTML, I'm overwriting calHTML and deleting the rest of the data.  Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

I think your problems is you didn't notice, that when you get the return value from `Object.assign(calHTML[k],v)` it returns the new value of `calHTML[k]` and not the value of `calHTML` itself, as you may meant.
Additionally, the `Object.assign` method modifies the target itself (e.g. your `calHTML[k]`) and doesn't create a copy of the object and modifying that like you would do with `{...calHTML[k], ...v}`.
So you have 2 options:

1. Simplify the two lines `let newCal = Object.assign(....calHTML = newCal;` to just `Object.assign(calHTML[k],v);`, because it modifies the object directly.
2. Replacing `Object.assign(calHTML[k],v);` to  `{...calHTML[k], ...v}`, and, `calHTML = newCal;` into `calHTML[k] = newCal;`, which is the thing made your bug.

For more information about `Object.assign` see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign).